# Blank spaces between text before listing, figures or tables

Tags: tables, spacing, listings

I'm writing my master thesis with the university official template for latex. Sometimes, when I load a listing, figure or table that does not fit in the current page (note that I'm using `\listing[H]` because I want the figure to be where it should), it shifts to the next page and consequently, the previous page creates this huge spaces between text. Is there a way that I can set my text aligned to top? At least, this way I would have only a big blank space at the end of the page.  There's a specific example bellow. Ignore the Portuguese red comment.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a small, but compilable example document to your question that can be used to replicate the problem. My guess is that a manual `\pagebreak` somewhere in your code is causing that bad spacing.

Comment: If the image belongs to the upper text, put a % in the line above (instead of the blank line). If it belongs to the next paragraph, do that replacement for the line below.  Kindly post the code so that the output can be checked after compiling as a MWE--you can see the guidelines

Comment: `\raggedbottom` might help.

Comment: @leandriis, that worked for me (even if its a bit of "hard coding"). Although there was a problem .. the footnotes also came to the middle of the page. Any chance you know a shortcut to make the same exact outcome but ignore the footnotes?

I tried replication a text sample and couldn't replicate those blank spaces. I believe it is something to do with my college template, which I definitely do not want to mess around.